# Adding Class to link_to_unless not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have searched on this and seen solutions, but something I'm doing is not working.  I have a nav-file and I'm using "link_to_unless" to either have my links be links or just text.  I'm trying to add a class to my link_to_unless line but it is not working.  I've added my class to other areas to test it and it works.  So, I'm inclined to think it is my link_to_unless.

I've tried:

```
<%= link_to_unless(request.env['REQUEST_URI'] =~ /customers\/create/, "Add", :controller => 'customers', :action => 'new', :class => "navs-sub") %>
```

and with curly braces:

```
<%= link_to_unless(request.env['REQUEST_URI'] =~ /customers\/create/, "Add", :controller => 'customers', :action => 'new', {:class => "navs-sub"}) %>
```

Adding the curly-braces gets me a syntax error (shown in part). It points to the spaces between the closing parens at the end of the line below:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tASSOC... 'new', {:class => "navs-sub"}) );@output_buffer.safe_concat...
```

my css:

```
.navs-sub {
  text-indent15px;
  background-color:#eee;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

Thanks for any help.
--jc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <%= link_to_unless((request.env['REQUEST_URI'] =~ /customers\/create/), "Add",{ :controller => 'customers', :action => 'new'}, {:class => "navs-sub"}) %>
```